# Finding data driven pages for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, data-driven-pages, map-series

I am working on importing .mxd files into ArcGIS Pro 1.2.  Everything appears to import smoothly except I lose my data driven pages. I read Pro 1.2 is supposed to support them.  Yet, when I do a geoprocessing search in Pro, nothing specific to data driven pages appears, and it is not located under Cartography Tools like it is for Desktop.

So, my questions is really broken down into three parts.

1. Does Pro 1.2 support data driven pages?
2. If so, where is it located?
3. Is there a way to import data driven pages into Pro from ArcMap?

Comment: If it is of interest, this morning I released an eLearning video tutorial entitled [Map Series made easy using ArcGIS Pro](http://discoverspatial.com/courses/map-series-made-easy-using-arcgis-pro).

Answer (score 9):

1. Data Driven Pages are available in ArcGIS Pro 1.2 under the name "Map Series"
   You can look at the Help page here.  It's not a Geoprocessing tool but a Layout option now.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/map-series.htm

[image: Enable Map Series]

2. When you import an MXD with Data Driven Pages, you need to go enable the Map Series and it will keep your original settings from the MXD.  It worked for me for several of my data driven MXDs

Answer (score 1):

You will find that this functionality is known as [Map Series](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/map-series.htm) pages in ArcGIS Pro:

> Map series gives you the ability to generate a set of output pages by
>   using a layout and iterating over a set of map extents. The extents
>   are defined by the features in a layer and are sometimes called tiles,
>   sections, or areas of interest (AOI). The layer that defines the
>   extents is referred to as an index layer. Any feature layer can serve
>   as the index layer.

When you tried importing an MXD with Data Driven Pages you may have seen an import notification of [20045: Data Driven Pages are not yet supported](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/20045-import-data-driven-pages.htm) which would be confusing and may need a documentation error/enhancement to be logged.